# MySQL - How to return distinct IDs where all rows for the same ID have null field value

Tags: mysql

I have a query with two joins that returns this data:

ID  Score
1   NULL
1   5
1   6
2   NULL
2   NULL
3   5
3   8
3   3
3   NULL
3   NULL
3   7
4   NULL
4   NULL
4   3
4   9

I would like to return the unique IDs which have a NULL value in the Score column for each of the rows with the same ID.  In this case, the query should only return one row with the ID of 2 since that is the only ID which has all NULL values in the Score column.

Thank you!

Comment: Show your original query

Comment: show your original query and your expected  result

Comment: how about `select distinct ID from your_table where ID not in (select ID from your_table where Score IS NOT NULL)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could aggregate your original query by making it as a sub select and aplly `count()` on score column which has null values, So if all values are NULL for a particular `ID` then count will return 0, thus using `having` clause you can filter your results using result of `count(Score)`

```
select ID,
  count(Score) count_null 
from (your query)t
group by ID
having count_null = 0
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e8c5/4) Based on your sample data set